# MYSQL#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'users' (
    'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'username' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    'first_name' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    'last_name' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    'email' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    'password' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    'sign_up_date' date NOT NULL,
    'activated' enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: And your **question** is?

Comment: Please read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

When you create your database you will need to initialize the defaults. For example:

```
CREATE DATABASE {your-db-here}
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1;

USE {your-db-here};
CREATE TABLE users (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
username varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
first_name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
last_name varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
email varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
password varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
sign_up_date date NOT NULL, 
activated enum('0','1') NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (id) 
);
```

InnoDB is the default engine